# Пропала документация (мануал) языка C на Linux

Tags: linux, c, man

После переустановки линукса (`Kali Linux`) пропала документация по языку `C` в `man`. Не подскажете, как её вернуть?

Comment: устновить маны? но так как линукс линуксу разница, то конкретных команд не будет

Comment: @KoVadim я указал дистрибутив. Ну просто я не думал, что имена пакетов с документацией будут отличаться.

Comment: просто было замечено, что устанавливающие Kali Linux часто задают вопросы, которые показывают их полное непонимания линукса. В кратце - есть разные менедждеры пакетов, а у них разные имена пакетов. так как это apt дистрибутив, то ищите apt search manpages, смотрите что подходит и устанавливайте - apt install <пакет>

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, помогли. Только не нужно обвинять людей в незнании. Все когда-то ничего не знали, но ничто не мешает мне изучать то, чего я пока не знаю.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия не всех людей, а тех, кто почему то решил поставить KaliLinux.

Comment: @KoVadim а что в этом такого? Что мешает изучать линукс на примере Kali Linux?

Comment: а вот не знаю, но почему то те, кто выбрали Kali Linux задают странные вопросы. Вот даже Ваш звучит также "пропала документация" - да не пропадала она, Вы ее просто не установили.

Comment: @KoVadim пропала, потому что раньше она устанавливалась по умолчанию, а теперь её нет. Разумеется, я понимаю, что её нужно устанавливать, и что она просто не установилась.